# Ushing shmat and shmget with forks to multiply a matrix

Tags: c++, c, fork, matrix-multiplication, fork-join

This is an assignment I'm working on for class. We must use forks, shmget, and shmat to create a multiplied matrix from two given matrices. Each fork does one instance of multiplication each (this is required).

```
size_t size = matrix1.height * matrix2.width * sizeof(int);
        int shmid = shmget(2000,size,0);
        int ** shm;
        shm = (int ** )shmat (shmid, 0 , 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix1.height; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix2.width; j++){
                cout << "i: " << i << "j: " << j << endl;
                shm[i][j] = 0;
                cout <<"a" << endl;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix1.height; i++){

            for (int j = 0; j < matrix2.width; j++){
                vector<int> row = matrix1.matrix_rows_by_columns[i];
                vector<int> column;
                for (int s = 0; s < matrix2.height; s++){
                    column.push_back(matrix2.matrix_rows_by_columns[s][j]);
                }
                for (int p = 0; p < row.size(); p++){
                    shm = (int ** )shmat (shmid, 0 , 0);
                    pid_t pid = fork();
                    if (pid == 0){
                        shm[i][j] += row[p] * column[p];
                    }
}
            }
```

My current issue is a segmentation fault on the line shm[i][j] that occurs on the first loop through (i = 0, j = 0). I also know I have to change the way I make pids to be in a array of pids. I also don't know how to join the forks at the end. I'm trying here but the documentation I've been able to find is very dense and my professor taught basically none of the coding aspect of the assignment.

Comment: your shared memory segment is **not** pointers to pointers to int.

Comment: what do you mean? Should it not be (int **)?

Comment: int** requires that you have an array of int* initialized in your shared memory segment, which is not the case.

Comment: So what can I do to make this a 2d array of ints? I'm completely new to this and like I said my professor teaches no code. He gave us an assignment and said use a 2d array for the matrix and multiply with forks passing the array with shmget and shmat. I'm totally new to shared memory segments.

Comment: This question is too broad. You need to start by learning how `fork` works, right now your code appears to be a [fork bomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb). Then you're going to need to learn about semaphores and/or mutexes to coordinate between processes. Then you need to experiment with shared memory. And once you've done all of that research, you can actually start to apply that knowledge to the task of multiplying matrices.

Comment: Your problem is not just lack of understanding of shared memory segments but basic C memory management, pointer arithmetic and such.

Comment: I understand how semaphores and mutexes work. I had to make a version of this assignment using pthreads which allowed me to pass a pointer to a vector to the thread. I am 100% serious when I tell you that the professor has done nothing to teach us how to code forks and shared memory. He is notorious as the worst professor in the computer science department. 


I would seriously appreciate it if you could help me out by pointing out specific issues with the code. Right now it's my pthread code with a fork instead of a new thread + shared memory.

Answer (score 0):

You must test the return values and `errno`. In your case `shmget` fails with `ENOENT`. See `man shmget` for details.